# Am I being upvoted for malicious reasons?

Tags: support

I'm probably the only one who would be concerned about getting a nice surge in upvotes, but in a few short hours since I checked last night, I have had +35. It seems that all of my recent questions/answers have been upvoted. I would only have expected my latest answer to have been upvoted.

Is it possible to check (meaning a mod, not me) who upvoted me since yesterday and see if it's possibly malicious?

- 35    today
- +10   6 hours ago    upvote  Where did Iron Man 2 take place?
- +10   8 hours ago    upvote  Why don't they cover themselves in zombie guts more often?
- +5    4 hours ago    upvote  Why did Tiny untie Mary and let her go?
- +5    4 hours ago    upvote  What is the recording played during the coffin scene?
- +5    4 hours ago    upvote  Family Guy ep 113 (Road to Germany) scene explanation

Comment: as a point of reference, a good answer (like the few me and some other high rep users get) have rep capped us in a day (+200 rep).  Only "malicious" up-votes out there is serial upvoting and puppet accounts. Which get noticed easily by ones higher up than the mods

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't think that sounds malicious at all, +35 is not a great deal.  These are recent posts voted upon.  Its likely that the 3 +5's are the same person, but I see this too - someone likes a post, checks the user, looks at some more answers.

The mods have a 'suspicious votes' tool - which checks whether a single user has a large number of their votes for another user. This is not showing anything, but I don't know exactly what criteria it looks at.

For +35 I don't see the need to dig further on this and see whether this is the same user.

Comment: Ok. What you said makes sense about visiting the user's other posts. It was so much about the amount of points, but the posts in which the votes were applied. I'll leave it at that then. thanks.

Comment: It might also have been a completely new user catching up on interresting questions.